# org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: missing requirement org.apache.camel)(version>=2.15.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))"

Tags: apache-camel, openshift, maven-plugin, jbossfuse

Just tried deploying my test jboss fuse application to openshift but gave me this error.

org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve dummy/0.0.0: missing requirement [dummy/0.0.0] 
osgi.identity; osgi.identity=flightsearch; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.0.SNAPSHOT,1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]" 
[caused by: Unable to resolve flightsearch/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [flightsearch/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.wiring.package; 
filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel)(version>=2.15.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))"]

I see that the dependencies are listed in my pom.xml

```html
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>Camel Blueprint Route</name>
<properties>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <!-- <fabric8.parentProfiles>feature-camel</fabric8.parentProfiles> <fabric8.profile>flightsearch</fabric8.profile> 
   <fabric8.features>camel</fabric8.features> <fabric8.featureRepos>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/${version:camel}/xml/features</fabric8.featureRepos> -->
</properties>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.10</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.10</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId> 
   <version>0.6.2</version> </dependency> -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>pax-web-jetty-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
    <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
    <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>snapshot.fusesource.org</id>
    <name>FuseSource Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>codehaus</id>
    <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>apache-repo-releases</id>
    <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
  </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
    <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
  </pluginRepository>
  <pluginRepository>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
    <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
  <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.7</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>bundle-manifest</id>
          <phase>process-classes</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>manifest</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <instructions>
          <Bundle-SymbolicName>flightsearch</Bundle-SymbolicName>
          <Private-Package>com.demo.flightsearch.flightsearch.*</Private-Package>
          <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
        </instructions>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
      <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <!-- <version>1.2.0.redhat-133</version> -->
      <configuration>
        <jolokiaUrl>http://xxxxxxx.rhcloud.com/jolokia</jolokiaUrl>
        <!-- <parentProfiles>feature-camel</parentProfiles> -->
        <profile>flightsearch</profile>
        <features>camel</features>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to add any other profiles to my container? Please advice.

Thank you.

Comment: All of this is due to deploying a codebase built with latest libraries on openshit which runs with older versions. I tried creating the fuse catridge with the latest git branches, but still the libraries are old. Also, tried configuring a custom "io.fabric8.version.properties" with my dev box library versions on openshift, but stuck with updating the fabric = 1.0.0.redhat-379 version! Any pointers?

Comment: Has anyone tried upgrading these libraries on openshift? 
camel = 2.12.0.redhat-610379 =====> 2.15.1.redhat-620133
cxf = 2.7.0.redhat-610379
hawtio = 1.2-redhat-379
fuse = 6.1.0.redhat-379
hawtio-swagger = 1.0.2
activemq = 5.9.0.redhat-610379
perfectus = 379
karaf = 2.3.0.redhat-610379
servicemix-nmr = 1.6.0.redhat-610379
fabric = 1.0.0.redhat-379
openshift.cart = jboss-fuse-6.1.x-379

Comment: A lesson learned is all the latest examples and demos out there are with latest libraries which will work on your dev box, but cannot be deployed on openshift! In my case, I am using <restConfiguration> which is not supported on older versions of camel! Now I have to either downgrade my services, or somehow upgrade the openshift PaaS.